# select2 / django-autocomplete-light - same object shows up multiple times in result set

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I use django-autocomplete-light and I want users to be able to search projects with either the projects number, head of project or titel of the project in an autocomplete field.

As soon as I add a third "| Q" line, I get the same object multiple times in my result list. I started with just name and project ID - there I could solve the problem by adding a "if isdigit()". But now I want to add additionally a search in the projects titel. Again, adding the third line with an "| Q" option results in some items showing up several times in the result set (3-5 times).

Any ideas what that could be? 
Can I somehow solve that or at lest reduce the result set in the end to just show each object once?

Thank you! :)

```
class SearchProjectAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    #todo: bug that show results 4-5 times when searched in titel
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = PubmaPublikation.objects.filter(typid__in=[222,223,224]).filter(zeigen=1)
        qs = qs.order_by('-erstellungsdatum')
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('pubmapublikationperson_set__person')
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('pubmapublikationsprache_set')

        if self.q:
            if self.q.isdigit():
                qs = qs.filter(Q(projektnummer__contains=self.q))

            else:
                qs = qs.filter(
                    (Q(pubmapublikationperson__rolle=1) & Q(pubmapublikationperson__person__vorname__icontains=self.q))
                    | (Q(pubmapublikationperson__rolle=1) & Q(pubmapublikationperson__person__nachname__icontains=self.q))
                    | (Q(pubmapublikationsprache__order=1) & Q(pubmapublikationsprache__titel__icontains=self.q)) #as soon as I add this third line I get results multiple times
                )

        #qs = qs.distinct()
            #does not work
            # django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB


        return qs
```

I tried distinct() on the queryset, but I do get the follwoing DB error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

seems like this comes from one of the fields. How can I make sure distinct is only used for the pk in an oracle DB?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the same row is joined again, use [Django distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: I tried distinct() already, but I do get the follwoing DB error:

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

seems like this comes from one of the fields. How can I make sure distinct is only used for the pk in an oracle DB?